# Scope of Alt hotkeys in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm using a tab control with several tabs. In each tab there is a custom user control with a set of button controls.

I've assigned hotkeys to my buttons like this in one of my user controls:

```
<Button Name="name">
   <Accesstext Text = "_Button"/>
</Button>
```

So that I get the underlined letter and can use Alt + B shortcut.

My problem is I have A LOT of buttons, and not enough keys to assign to them all. I cant use Alt + B in any of my other tabpages again.

So is there a solution where I can reuse these in different tabpages? That is Alt + B should trigger a button on my current tabpage, and if I go to a different tab, Alt + B should trigger a button on that tab.

And I'm aware of the KeyGestures way, but I would really like to get the automatic underlining of the letter when I press Alt.

Answer (score 0):

With TabControl.SelectedItem you can get the current selected tab. Then you can play with this value under an if statement.

Regards,

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the original question.

Comment: No not really. Anyone else have any ideas?